# Converting heat pump thermostat to honeywell t9

Tags: hvac, thermostat, heat-pump

I'm almost confident in installing new Honeywell T9 thermostat but niggling doubt.
I have two simple heat pump systems, each with own thermostat.

The original honeywell thermostat TH1210DH wiring

| Code | Wire Color | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| O | Orange | ? |
| G | Green | ? |
| Y | Yellow | ? |
| Aux/E | White | ? |
| C | Blue | Common 24vac |
| R | Red | Factory jumper to “not used” |

The first doubt is the white wire. It goes Aux/E on the old thermostat and the new one has potential candidates to "W", "E", and "Aux/W2".
I think I doubt it because I am unsure about what the wires should be doing... The GOY seems pretty standard. White gets confusing, but because this is a simpler system I think it is likely just going to W for initial heating.

The T9 wiring table and my guesses as to color and function below

| Code | Wire color | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Y | yellow | switched to cooling |
| Yz |  |  |
| G | green | switched to fan |
| C | blue | power common |
| A |  |  |
| o/b | orange | switched to reversing |
| aux/w2 |  |  |
| E |  |  |
| W | white | switched to heating |
| K |  |  |
| R | red | power 24vac |
| RC |  |  |

The wiring at the air handler seems to be like so

| t-stat wire | 1st conn | 2nd conn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Blue | blue | purple |
| White | white | white |
| Red | red | red |
| Orange | orange | n/a |
| Green | green | green on board |
| Yellow | water sensor sw | through to yellow |

Picture of wiring, attempt to spread out for tracing:
[image: picture in air handler]

Hopefully someone can tell me how simple it is and set me straight.  My guesses on purpose of the wire/colors based on this [article](https://inspectapedia.com/heat/Thermostat-Wire-Color-Codes.php)

The second doubt is the second thermostat which is a Trane and initially a little more confusing because the labels are not as similar. Here, white goes to X2 and is simultaneously jumpered over to W1. My guess is white still goes to W and no jumper is needed, but that's the biggest doubt.

Comment: Can you post photos of the air-handler end of the thermostat wiring please?

Comment: added photo and table of wire tracing. Thanks for asking!

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your air handler, for that matter?